# How to show success of a form in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

there is a selectbox . and i wrote a function for onchange method of that via ajax. it works good when i show form success in a div .my question is how to show my form success in an iframe?
here is my snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("[name='count']").on('change', function() {
    var url = "/page2.html";
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: $("#form").serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $("#box").html(data)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" id="form">
 <select name="count">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select> 
</form>

<iframe name="box" id="box"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An iframe has it's own window so you can't access it directly the same way you do other elements

You can use [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to access that window and do something like:

```
$("#box").contents().find('body').html(data);
```

Seems to me you don't need ajax for this and could simply submit the form with `target` as the iframe

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3hf1s0v3/)**</kbd>

Comment: but how can i send my form to action page?

Comment: if you use `target` on form and set to iframe id the response would render in the iframe by using the url of the form action

Answer (score 0):

you could access the content of your iframe like this :
Assuming you are in your "success()" function and the iframe src is not cross-origin

```
var iframe = $('#box');

//Cross browser compatility
var iframe_doc = iframe[0].contentWindow || iframe[0].contentDocument;
if (iframe_doc.document) {
      iframe_doc = iframe_doc.document;
}
iframe_doc.open();
iframe_doc.write("<html><head></head><body></body></html>");
var iframe_body =  $(iframe_doc).find('body');
iframe_body.html(data)
```